# spontaneous disintegration of an unstable particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability

Suppose one wants to describe an unstable particle that spontaneously disintegrates with a life time say "tau". In that case the total probability of finding the particle is not constant. But should decrease at some rate, say exponential rate. Now my question is that the textbook asks me calculate the rate of change of probability by inserting a complex potential in the schrodinger equation, I did that and indeed found that the probability itself decays with an exponential rate. I would like to know why does one get this by introducing a complex potential? And instead of spontaneous disintegration of the particle if I had decay, lets say that the particle decays exponentially. Then I know that the probability of finding a particle in some region changes as the particle decays, but how do I calculate the rate of change of probability, because now I have the fact that mass is a function of time, how does this fit into the schrodinger equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "interaction" representation.

If you call $|\psi'(t)>$ a desintegrating particle (due to the complex potential $V(t) = iv$, $v$ constant) and $|\psi(t)>$ a "free" particle (potential $V = 0$) , and , you could write the evolution equation as :

$$|\psi'(t)> = e^{- i S_{interaction}} |\psi(t)> = e^{i \int_0^tV((u)du} |\psi(t)>$$
$$|\psi'(t)> = e^{- vt} |\psi(t)>$$

Here $|\psi(t)>$  and $|\psi'(t)>$ are in the "interaction" representation.

So, you can make any calculus you want, for instance,  $$\psi'(x,t) = <x|\psi'(t)> = e^{- vt} <x|\psi(t)> = e^{- vt} \psi(x,t)$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is my first course in QM I have not yet encountered "interaction representation". But since you mentioned it, I googled about it and learnt a bit. I want to tell you what I found so that someone can correct me if I am wrong. I found that the Hamiltonian for a system can be split into two parts one non interacting, the other interaction based. So is it due to this interaction (complex potential)hamiltonain in the schrodinger equation, the wave function itself has an exponential rate of decay? So thereof any quantity of interest has this character?

Comment: An other way to see that, is that the free particle wave function $\psi(x, t)$ obeys the free Schrodinger equation : $i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(x, t) = H_o \psi(x, t)$. Now, if you take, a wave function $\psi'$ defined as $\psi'(x, t) = e^{ \frac{i}{\hbar} \int_0^tV((u)du} \psi(x, t)$, this new wave function $\psi'$ obeys the modified Schrodinger equation with potential V, that is : $i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi'(x, t) = (H_o + V) \psi'(x, t)$. So with a complex potential, $V = iv$, where $v$ is constant, you automatically get a negative exponential term for $\psi'$

Comment: And this negative exponential term for $\psi'$, that is $e^{- vt}$ is precisely the exponential rate of decay (this is the same thing)

Comment: One way to achieve this decay is by introducing complex potential. Are there other ways of doing this?

Comment: In fact, the correct framework to studying these thinds, is Quantum Field Theory (QFT). In this framework, decay means simply transformation of one kind of particle into other kinds of particles. For instance,  if you have a term like $A(x,t)B^2(x,t)$ in the Lagrangian (density) of the theory, it gives the possibility that a particle $A$ decays in $2$ particles $B$. Of course, there are precise rules for all this (sometimes 1 =>2 decays are allowed, sometimes not), so look also to Feynman Diagrams, which are the graphical and mathematical rules for calculating transitions amplitudes  in QFT.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Perhaps I'll have to wait until i study QFT.